NVIDIA G210 card driver seems to have been corruted on 22.4, How to reinstall?
The NVIDIA driver for G210 card seems to have been disturbed and gives low resolution. My system is Ubuntu 22.04 with kernel 6.8.0-40-generic
tried to replace with a new card, same result.
Look forward to solution.
